# javadoc cannot be accessed offline

Tags: javadoc

> ```
> Hey i am using Eclipse mars on windows 10 and everytime i hover my mouse on a method 
> or anything, it says
> ```

"The attached Javadoc could not be retrieved as the specified Javadoc
    location is either wrong or 
    currently not accessible."

```
but it shows the javadoc when i am connected to internet.       
this was not the case before,how do i restore it??
```

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to Window, Preferences, and navigate to the javadoc options or type javadoc where it says 'type filter text'. Check if the options 'Process Javadoc comments' is checked. It may ask you to do a full rebuild of your projects after you check/uncheck that option.[image]